# Xcode 6 iPhone only app crashing on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I sent an app to apple with iPhone-only settings. Trust me, I have looked over all the settings to make sure the target device family is iPhones. When I sent the app to apple, however, they rejected the app on the basis that: "We found that your app crashed on iPad running iOS 8, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Your app crashed when we pressed Play.

This occurred when your app was used on Wi-Fi."

I understand why apple would say this, but at the same time I do not. I tested the app on the simulators on iPad, and the errors that I got in the debugging area were:

`CUICatalog: Can't find rendition for name: mainMenuPicture scale factor: 2 device idiom: 2 device subtype: 0
SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "mainMenuPicture"`

On iPhones, all of the mainMenuPictures (in the asset catalogs) work fine. In fact, everything does, except that when the same app runs on iPad, this happens. In the asset catalogs, I only included iPhone and iPhone A4 screen types (so my asset consists of 1x, 2x, 3x, and Retina 4 2x images). Would this be the interference?

Please help. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here are the pictures with the crashlogs and the code when it happens.

[image: Compiler Error Message]

Here is the asset catalog, which works on the iPhone device family, but doesn't on iPad:
[image: Asset Catalog]

I have tried renaming the `textureWithImage:` to `textureWithImageNamed`, which returned a blank image and ran (with many more errors however). That is not the ultimate cause of the error.

Comment: Oh, and on the iPads, the pictures do load even though there was an "Error loading image resource".

Comment: You should also test your app on real iPads. The simulator may not crash where it will do on the real device. It can also happen that a release version crashes where a debug version does it.

Comment: Your comment, not to be mean, is missing the point of my post. The simulator DOES crash when run on iPad, because I did not assume it should be ran on an iPad. I posted the errors above as to why it crashes. I can verify this because I have, in fact, tested on iPhones (real devices) and each worked, thus proving it is a device specific issue.

Comment: Oh I misread your post then. All iPhone apps should be able to run on iPad as iPhone simulated apps. You can test this with any app from the App Store. -- Regarding your crash - can you provide more information like a stacktrace and/or the code which crashes? The image must be loaded somewhere.

Comment: Sure, i'll edit the post to include pictures in a second

Comment: It's weird that the asset catalog explicitly says "iPhone". Can you set it to "Universal" in the settings pane, assign the images to universal instead of iPhone and check if it helps? - Also when you run your app on iPad, is it full-sized or an iPhone app simulation?

Comment: It is full sized. I will try the to set it to "Universal", thank you for the idea; however, how would I generate the longer iPhone 5 screen? (In the asset catalog there is the Retina 4 2x that isn't in the Universal pane). Thanks!

Comment: Can you check both, Universal and iPhone? Then you could make Universal the baseline and also add long iPhone support. I'm on Windows right now so I cannot test that by myself. -- Are you really sure the app is not enabled for iPad? It should run in iPhone simulation mode if not. But that only applies to real iPads, not the simulator.

Comment: It seemed to have fixed the issue with the agUp texture (With multiple asset catalogs and rotating textures it will take some time to create a new version with all Universal instead of iPhone). Since it's very late where I live and I'm procrastinating on other papers for school, I'll get back to you tomorrow. It is EXTREMELY weird why this happens with Xcode 6 / iOS8 and not the versions before those. Thanks in advance if everything works!

Comment: As to your latter comment, yes I am 100% SURE that it has no iPad support. In xCode5, I would test the iPads on the simulators and would be able to toggle the 1x and 2x button unlike these simulators. Weird. But no, I did not change any settings as to target device family

Comment: Your answer was sufficient for me to relatively fix my bug. If a new issue persists, I believe it would require a new question for integrity purposes of this site. Please post your previous answer in the answer section below so I could mark it answered and correct. Thank you! 
P.S. What solve the issue is setting the iPhone catalogs to Universal (I have not tried using both universal and iphone in the same catalog, but I do not believe I will have to). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird that the asset catalog explicitly says "iPhone". Can you set it to "Universal" in the settings pane, assign the images to universal instead of iPhone (excluding long iPhone which is not universal) and check if it helps?

Comment: Thanks again haha it makes me happy to finally make things work!